# JAva + postresql запросы на объединение таблиц

Tags: java, postgresql

вот скажем у меня есть две таблицы product  и type
я открываю консоль sql и делаю запрос 
Вывести все продукты и их тип  (но вывести все продукты у которых тип 2 (т.е. тип СЫР)).

```
select p.name, t.name from product as p inner join type as t on p.type_id = t.id where p.type_id = 2;
```

так всё работает
а как это описать в java?

я написал так

```
  PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM product as p INNER JOIN type as t on p.type_id = t.id WHERE p.type_id = ?");
            st.setInt(1, 2);

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s ", rs.getString("name")));
            }
```

так то работает выводит все продукты 
Пармезан
Рокфо
Галанский
Российский

но как мне сделать чтобы выводился их тип ? t.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT p.name, t.name FROM product as p INNER JOIN type as t on p.type_id = t.id WHERE p.type_id = ?");
            st.setInt(1, 2);

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
            }
```